# How to change all hidden folders/files to visible in a multiple sub directories

Tags: linux, perl, rename, file-rename

I have hundreds of sub directories in a directory that all have hidden files in them that I need to remove the period at the beginning of them to make them visible. I found a command to go into each directory and change them to make them visible but I need to know how to make this command work from one directory up.

```
rename 's/\.//;' .*
```

I have tried about an hour to modify this to work one level up but don't understand the Perl string enough to do it. If someone could help out I am sure it's simple and I just can't land on the right answer.

Comment: You could probably get a list of all dirs/files that need to be renamed via the `find` command – but recursion through a directory you are also renaming might lead to problems.

Comment: I just need to add ./* to that command basically I dont need to rename in the parent directory I ONLY need to rename in the hundreds of sub directories. So I need to find a way to tell it to point to all the directories one level down instead of the way its written which is to the current directory.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires a find that supports the `+` (can use `\;` instead, which will call `rename` multiple times), but even [POSIX find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) specifies it:

```
find -mindepth 1 -depth -exec rename -n 's{/\.([^\/]*$)}{/$1}' {} +
```

- The `-depth` option prevents directories from being renamed before all the files in them are renamed
- `-mindepth 1` prevents find from trying to rename the current directory, `.`.
- `-n` is to just print what would be renamed instead of actually renaming (has to be removed to do the renaming).
- The regular expression removes the last period after which there are no forward slashes, if it is preceded by a forward slash.

`rename` doesn't overwrite existing files, unless the `-f` ("force") option is used.

For a test directory structure like this:

```
.
├── .dir1
│   ├── .dir2
│   │   ├── .dir3
│   │   │   └── .file2
│   │   └── .file1
│   ├── file3
│   └── .file6
├── dir5
│   └── .file5
├── .file4
├── test1.bar
└── test1.foo
```

the output is

```
rename(./dir5/.file5, ./dir5/file5)
rename(./.file4, ./file4)
rename(./.dir1/.file6, ./.dir1/file6)
rename(./.dir1/.dir2/.file1, ./.dir1/.dir2/file1)
rename(./.dir1/.dir2/.dir3/.file2, ./.dir1/.dir2/.dir3/file2)
rename(./.dir1/.dir2/.dir3, ./.dir1/.dir2/dir3)
rename(./.dir1/.dir2, ./.dir1/dir2)
rename(./.dir1, ./dir1)
```

and the result after removing `-n` is

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   │   ├── dir3
│   │   │   └── file2
│   │   └── file1
│   ├── file3
│   └── file6
├── dir5
│   └── file5
├── file4
├── test1.bar
└── test1.foo
```

Comment: Interesting about POSIX and `+`, because I've run into numerous people that had a `find` that didn't accept `+`.

Comment: @ikegami It's not even that new, already the 2004 spec lists it, but I don't rely on it being around on every system.

Answer (score 3):

`safely_unhide`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename qw( fileparse );
for (@ARGV) {
   my $o = $_;

   my ($fn, $dir_qfn) = fileparse($_);
   $fn =~ s/^\.//
      or next;

   my $n = "$dir_qfn/$fn";
   if (stat($n)) {
      warn("Skipping \"$o\": \"$n\" already exists\n");
      next;
   }
   elsif (!$!{ENOENT}) {
      warn("Skipping \"$o\": Can't stat \"$n\": $!\n");
      next;
   }

   rename($n, $o)
      or warn("Skipping \"$o\": Can't rename to \"$n\": $!\n");
}
```

Usage:

```
find -type f -exec safely_unhide {} +          # Supports all file names. Requires GNU find
find -type f | xargs safely_unhide             # Doesn't support newlines in file names.
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 safely_unhide  # Supports all file names.
```

Drop `-type f` and add `-depth` if you want to rename hidden dirs too.

Comment: find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 safely_unhide
Skipping "./safely_unhide": Can't stat "safely_unhide//": Not a directory
Skipping "./remove_hidden": Can't stat "remove_hidden//": Not a directory
Skipping "./T2/.test3": Can't rename to ".test3//T2/": No such file or directory

Comment: Fixed. Had the values returned by `fileparse` in the wrong order.